# How to add function to namespace

Tags: typescript, lunrjs

I have a Node.js typescript application based on `lunr` and `lunr-multilanguage`. Loaded `@type/lunr` but no type definition exists for `lunr-multilanguage`. Trying to add something to my source code to satisfy the compiler. This is the original code:

```
import lunr from "lunr";
require("lunr-languages/lunr.stemmer.support")(lunr);
require("lunr-languages/lunr.multi")(lunr);
require("lunr-languages/lunr.it")(lunr);
const englishItalianSupport = lunr.multiLanguage("en", "it");
```

Typescript complains: `error TS2339: Property 'multiLanguage' does not exist on type 'typeof import("D:/Project/node_modules/@types/lunr/index.d.ts")'.`

I tried to add (based on the lunr `index.d.ts` definition file):

```
declare module "lunr" {
    namespace lunr {
        class Index {
            multiLanguage(a: string, b: string): any;
        }
    }
}
```

before or after the lunr module import, but the error persists.
Typescript documentation speaks of type merging, but here I don't see where to look. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue now with "lunr.multiLanguage", could you please tell me how you solved this issue?

Comment: See below the last three comments

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `lunr` definition file you can see:

```
export as namespace lunr;
export = lunr;
```

So to extend it you declare:

```
declare namespace lunr
{
    function multiLanguage(a: string, b: string): any;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not merged in the namespace, it overwrites the namespace, so it starts complaining about `lunr.tokenizer` missing etc.

Comment: I am ashamed of myself. The workaround is to edit lunr definitions file (`node_modules/lunr/index.d.ts`) and add after `generateStopWordFilter` definition: `function multiLanguage(lang1: string, lang2: string): any;`

Comment: That should merge and does so for me. And i would highly recommend not ever modifying the contents in `node_modules` as updating modules will probably overwrite your changes.

Comment: @SiliconValley: You may need to rename your declaration file to `lunr.d.ts` depending on your TS compiler configuration.